# Does existence of $\sup (A \cup B)$ imply existence of $\sup A$ and $\sup B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples, order-theory, supremum-and-infimum

Let there be defined an order $\langle X, \leq \rangle$ and two sets $A, B \subseteq X$. Does existence of $\sup (A \cup B)$ imply that both $\sup A$ and $\sup B$ exist?

Here is my reasoning so far:
Let $x \in X$, $x = \sup(A\cup B)$, then $x$ is an upper bound for both $A$ and $B$. I cannot see however if that means that both $A$ and $B$ have least upper bounds.

Comment: Consider $X=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid x<0\}$ and $B=(0,1]$. Here $A\cup B$ has supremum $1$, but $A$ doesn't have supremum.

Comment: @owl Indeed, Thanks!